# Apache Camel Restlet - Unable to set Authorization parameter in Header

Tags: authorization, apache-camel, restlet-2.0

We are trying to initiate a REST webservice call Using Apache Camel Restlet Component and it was successful.

But we are not able to retrieve the Authorization header property value from request object which we have set in Apache Camel Exchange Header.

```
exchange.getIn().setHeader("Authorization", "abcde");
```

Actually we are making this REST call through Camel's Dynamic router.
Can someone suggest how to set the Authorization header in Apache Camel Exchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. It might help someone. For adding custom headers in restlet,

```
Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<>();
Series<Header> customHeaders = new Series<Header>(Header.class);
customHeaders.add(new Header("Authorization", "abcde"));
headers.put(HeaderConstants.ATTRIBUTE_HEADERS, customHeaders);
```